# Из hex в asm на Linux

Tags: ассемблер, linux

Есть кусок кода в машинных кодах. Необходимо сконвертировать его в ассемблерный код.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Дополнительная информация:

1. Целевая платформа linux
2. Нужно преобразовать именно кусок кода, а не весь бинарник (поэтому gdb и objdump не подходят)

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @gg4me, а что мешает *преобразовать* **весь код** и взять оттуда кусок?

Comment: @niki-timofe, ты вообще о чем? =)

---
@gg4me, если вам надо просто тупо поглазеть на HEX-код в ассемблерном виде, то можно воспользоваться инструментами наподобие дизассемблера в Windows.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers

Comment: @niki-timofe ну предположим я схватил по сети пакет с шеллкодом и хочу разобраться чего эта гадость делает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отдельные куски кода довольно неплохо дизассемблирует утилита [rasm](http://radare.org/y/?p=examples&f=rasm) из [radare](http://radare.org) (the reverse engineering framework)

Answer (score 2):

Считаю что [IDA Pro](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA)
может неплохо справиться с поставленной задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Лет шесть назад мне требовалось открыть сильно битый ELF, тогда помогла система lida ([Linux Interactive DisAssembler](http://lida.sourceforge.net/)). Судя по сайту она давно не поддерживается, к сожалению, не уверен, что работоспособна. Гораздо дольше поддерживалась библиотека [libdisasm](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html), на которой основана lida, может, удастся использовать ее напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

Я могу посоветовать (Хотя не проверял прокатит ли), открыть нех код под HIEW32, дальше начать изучение самого кхм... кода, кода. Клавиша F4 и выбрать Decode.

Comment: @AlexMelk, использовать под Linux проприетарный инструмент при наличии [свободных аналогов](http://hte.sourceforge.net/) ИМХО как-то не кошерно.